# Assert that a function changes a stateful value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

So, here is a simplified version of my code.

This is my custom hook.

```
export const useStep = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState<Steps>("sending");

  const changeStep = (newStep: Steps) => setStep(newStep);

  return { step, changeStep };
}
```

This is my test file

```
const { result } = renderHook(() => useStep());

const { step, changeStep, resetStep } = result.current;

...

it("should change step value when `changeStep` is called", async () => {
  expect(step).toBe("sending");

  changeStep("verifying");

  await waitFor(() => expect(step).toBe("verifying"));
})
```

I've already tried many things, but none of them seems to work. `step` value stays as `'sending'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in the doc, see [Updates](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/basic-hooks#updates).

> NOTE: There's a gotcha with updates. `renderHook` mutates the value of `current` when updates happen so **you cannot destructure its values as the assignment will make a copy locking into the value at that time.**

So the correct way is:

`index.ts`:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

type Steps = 'sending' | 'verifying';

export const useStep = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState<Steps>('sending');

  const changeStep = (newStep: Steps) => setStep(newStep);

  return { step, changeStep };
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useStep } from '.';

describe('72209087', () => {
  it('should change step value when `changeStep` is called', async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(useStep);
    expect(result.current.step).toBe('sending');
    act(() => {
      result.current.changeStep('verifying');
    });
    expect(result.current.step).toBe('verifying');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/72209087/index.test.ts (25.293 s)
  72209087
    ✓ should change step value when `changeStep` is called (17 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        28.622 s
```

Comment: I can't believe how simple the solution was. Thank you!